# SQL join 3 таблицы

Tags: sql, join

SQL код:

```
create table claim(ClaimID int);

insert into claim (ClaimID)
values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

create table tbl1(ClaimID int, Amnt float);

insert into tbl1 (ClaimID, Amnt)
values (1, 10),
(2, 20),
(2, 20),
(3, 30);

create table tbl2(ClaimID int, Amnt float);

insert into tbl2 (ClaimID, Amnt)
values (1, 10),
(1, 10),
(4, 40),
(3, 30);

select c.claimid, count(tbl1.claimid), count(tbl2.claimid)
from claim c
inner join tbl1 on c.claimid = tbl1.claimid
left join tbl2 on c.claimid = tbl2.claimid
group by tbl1.claimid, tbl2.claimid
;
```

Результат:

```
1|2|2
2|2|0
3|1|1
```

Вопрос: почему `count(tbl1.claimid)` возвращает 2 а не 1?

Upd: Почему присоединение tbl2 влияет на количество IDs в tbl1?

Спасибо!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/580a1c/5

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в таблице tbl2 у вас две записи с id=1, из-за чего одна и та же запись tbl1 считается два раза.

Я бы переписал запрос таким образом.

```
    select c.claimid
      , (select count(*) q from tbl1 where c.claimid = claimid) q1
      , (select count(*) q from tbl2 where c.claimid = claimid) q2
    from claim c
    where exists(select ClaimID from tbl1 where c.claimid = claimid)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все равно непонятно почему присоединение tbl2 влияет на количество IDs в tbl1?

Comment: count(tbl1.claimid) не выбирает количество уникальных значений tbl1.claimid, а просто берет их количество в результирующих строках запроса, а на ID=1 результирующих строки две, т.к. вы делаете join таблицы tbl2, в которой две строки с id=1. Если вы например присоедините таблицу tbl3, (хоть left, хоть inner), в которой будет три записи с id=1, то count(tbl1.claimid) вам должен вернуть число 6.

Comment: Можете вовнутрь count() поместить distinct, но это так же не совсем то,что вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо, вроде понял. В общем количество id в tbl1 и tbl2 будут всегда перемножаться? Если в tbl1 будет 3 id = 1 и в tbl2 id = 3, то count(tbl1.claimid) вернет 9.
То, что count(tbl1.claimid) не выбирает количество уникальных значений tbl1.claimid, это понятно, там нет distinct. Я думал будет подсчитываться общее количество ids = 1 только в tbl1.

Comment: да, выводятся все варианты подходящие под условия вашего запроса, а count() просто подсчитывает количество, сколько раз требуемое поле вывелось со значением неравным null